# A handler for custom jQuery event, regardless of its namespace?

Tags: namespaces, jquery

I'm curious about the following...

jQuery allows us to define custom events (e.g. `myevent`) and trigger these. It's also possible to add an extra layer of granularity by adding namespaces (e.g. `myevent.namesp`).

I want to know if it's possible to write an event handler for all custom events having the same name, but *regardless of their namespace*.

For example, if I have the following code:

```
$('input').on('myevent.namesp', function(e) {
    alert('The immediate event fired');
});

$('body').on('myevent', function() {
    alert('Caught the delegated event');
});

$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).trigger('myevent.namesp');
});
```

The 'immediate event' is fired, but the delegated event handler is not (because it's not bound using the specific namespace). Is it possible to do something like

```
$('body').on('myevent.*', function() { /* Handler for all 'myevent' events */ });
```

I know using `.on()` in this way isn't possible, but you get the idea.

You can see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VwU68/

Answer (score 1):

Namespacing events makes them more specific; if the event trigger does not have a namespace, then *all* events of that type will be triggered regardless of namespace.  Therefore, you have to change the `.trigger` to use `'myevent'` instead.

You can, however, have multiple namespaces and trigger the highest level one (apparently; I didn't even know this): http://jsfiddle.net/VwU68/2/ -- you may be able to use that to your advantage.